# Why did Henry shoot through his jacket to kill sniper?

Tags: gemini-man

In scifi cloning concept movie *Gemini Man* (2019), Henry was followed by a sniper after he took shelter at Baron's Residence.

Then, he left the residence and saw the sniper's reflection in the pool 
and tried to shoot with his silenced gun through his jacket:

[image]

Why did he shoot through his jacket to kill the sniper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sniper were aware that Henry was about to shoot him, he would likely dodge or try to shoot first. By firing from behind the cover of his jacket, where the sniper would be unable to see what he was doing, Henry could possibly secure the advantage of surprise with that first shot.